# Stiffness of a system of differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

For a university assignment I've been given three systems of differential equations:

$$\bf{\dot{y}} = \begin{pmatrix}-2 & 1\\ 1 & -2\end{pmatrix} * \bf{y} + \begin{pmatrix}2 * \sin(t)\\ 2*(\cos(t) - \sin(t))\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\bf{\dot{y}} = \begin{pmatrix}-2 & 1\\ 998 & -999\end{pmatrix} * \bf{y} + \begin{pmatrix}2 * \sin(t)\\ 999*(\cos(t) - \sin(t))\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\bf{\dot{y}} = \begin{pmatrix}-2 & 1\\ -1.999 & 0.999\end{pmatrix} * \bf{y} + \begin{pmatrix}2 * \sin(t)\\ -0.999*(\cos(t) - \sin(t))\end{pmatrix}$$

For each system, the eigenvalues and the stiffness ratio $S = \frac{\left|Re(\lambda_{max})\right|}{\left|Re(\lambda_{min})\right|}$ have to be calculated. Then the systems should be solved using ode45 and an appropiate stiff solver in MATLAB.

This leads to the following results:

[image]
[image]

[image]

System 2 is clearly a stiff problem, right? But why isn't system three showing the same behaviour as the stiffness ratio $S$ is the same for both problems?

MATLAB-code for reference: https://pastebin.com/Zaj8Ca1j

**EDIT:** I just noticed i forgott to label the axes, the x-axis is the time $t$ and the y-axis is $y_1$ and $y_2$

Comment: You didn't implement stiffness ratio correctly. What you describe here is not what you wrote in your code. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation#Stiffness_ratio However, you are right, systems 2 and 3 have the same ratio.